# Threefold composition of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, geometric-series

For $|r|<1$, we have the geometric series $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}}$. I'll call the RHS $G(r)$ and the LHS $S(r)$. It is clear that $G(G(G(r)))=r$, even if $r=1$ with the usual convention $1/\infty=0$:
$$
G(G(r)) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-r}} = 1-\frac{1}{r};\qquad G(G(G(r))) = G(1-1/r) = \frac{1}{1-(1-1/r)}=r
$$The goal: Is there a meaningful "series-side" analog of $S(S(S(r)))$? I found an interpretation of one composition. Since the series is infinitely differentiable, it's easy to see it satisfies the differential equation:
$$
\frac{d^{n}}{d r^n} \frac{S(r)}{n!} = \left(S(r)\right)^{n+1}
$$This gives
$$
S(S(r))=1+ S(r) + S(r)^2 +  S(r)^3 +S(r)^4 +S(r)^5+\cdots,
$$which we can write as a sum of derivatves
$$
=1+ \frac{S(r)}{1} + \frac{S'(r)}{1} +  \frac{S''(r)}{2} +\frac{S'''(r)}{6} +\frac{S''''(r)}{24}+\cdots,
$$which when put into the Taylor series formula reduces rather nicely
$$
=1+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{S^{(n)}(r)}{n!} =1+ S(r+1) =1+ \frac{1}{1-(r+1)} = 1-\frac{1}{r}.
$$But I haven't found a pretty way to compose once more with $S$ and get back the identity, $r$; in other words, a series proof that $S(1-1/r)=r$. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no real (or complex) $r$ such that $S(r)$ converges, *and* $S(u)$ converges at $u=S(r)$, *and* $S(v)$ converges at $v = S(u)$. That makes it difficult to assign a meaning to $S(S(S(r)))$ at all.

Comment: Difficult but not impossible perhaps…

Answer (score 1):

It's no different from the usual geometric series, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Big(1-\frac1r\Big)^n = \frac{1}{1-(1-\frac1r)}=r,$$
so long as $|1-\frac 1r|<1$.

Comment: Hmm, you're not wrong but I was hoping for something a little sexier. ;) (Thanks for your answer though!)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the series analogue of composition: to formally compose two series
$$
F(x) = a_0+a_1x+ \ldots \qquad G(x)=b_0+b_1x+\ldots
$$
i.e. to make sense of $F(G(x))$, you need to have $b_0=0$. This is because, formally, it only makes sense to evaluate $F$ at $0$, and in order to have $G(0)=0$ you need to have $b_0=0$. In your case, $G(0)=1$, making everything very difficult.

In fact, if you tried to evaluate $G(G(r))$ you get a lot of infinite sums of positive integers:
$$
1+(1+r+\ldots)+(1+r+\ldots)^2 + (1+r+\ldots)^3+\ldots$$$$ = (1+1+1+\ldots )+ (1+2+3+\ldots )r+\ldots 
$$

Comment: I had realized this, but I thought perhaps some form of continuation or renormalization could smooth it out. I'll upvote but with respect I don't think this is going to get the bounty.